# Questions about data transfer between java web layers

Tags: java, web

I'd like to ask some questions about the best practice of implementing a java web.
In a java web application, we split it into different layers: **view layer**, **service layer**, **DAO layer**, and we have some data model for those layers(according to alibaba's java developing manuals):

1. DO: correspond to data structure in database, used to transfer from DAO layer to service layer
2. BO: business object, transferred from service layer to view layer
3. VO: view object, exposed to rendering engine by view layer

Then I am confused about how to organize the data model for the request going through view layer, service layer and DAO layer, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: It's a mere convention, now with the SpringDataREST you get the same DO across all the layers of your application. If you want to hide/show something you can write projections on top of that.

Answer (score 0):

There are many web frameworks which have solved this problem already and you needn't implement them from scratch. Some of the most popular web frameworks are -

Spring MVC for Java - https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html
Django for Python - https://www.djangoproject.com
Express for node.js - http://expressjs.com
and many more.

Pick one of these framework and read their tutorial to understand how to implement MVC in that framework. For data model and OR Mapping you would need tools like JPA or Hibernate (for java apps) which can be configured into the web framework. Tutorial for the web frameworks will contain information on how to configure the OR mapper.

The MVC design pattern is same (as you read from Alibaba), however it has many implementations and flavors.